widget is overflowing under consumer widget

import 'package:cleamba/Data/Products.dart';
import 'package:cleamba/Listners/Fav_listener.dart';
import 'package:cleamba/Pool.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Productfilerpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return productfilterpagestate();
  }
}

class productfilterpagestate extends State<Productfilerpage> {
  List<String> suma = ['asdasd', 'asfdfasas', 'asffrwe', 'wqqqxs', 'asdwqsa'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Products> products_list = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      products_list.add(Products(
          name: 'Vaylirk makie vases',
          price: 12.1223,
          productID: 100 + i,
          imageurl: 'sd',
          description: 'sads',
          category: 'Vases'));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Pool.primarycolor,
          title: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Autocomplete(
                    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                      return suma.where((element) => element
                          .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()));
                    },
                    fieldViewBuilder: (context, textEditingController,
                            focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) =>
                        TextFormField(
                      controller: textEditingController,
                      focusNode: focusNode,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Search...",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list)),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.tune)),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
              ],
            ),
          )),
      body: GridView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisExtent: 200,
          ),
          itemCount: products_list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542234161-b0394bb94542?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D'),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                products_list[index].name!,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                products_list[index].category!,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                '₹ ' + products_list[index].price.toString(),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Center(
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Provider.of<Fav_Listener>(context,
                                          listen: false)
                                      .add_favorites(products_list[index]);
                                },
                              ),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}


Error : Bottom overflowed by 999362 pixles
Actually Iam trying to render  an gridview . My grid view item have one Button which surrounded by Consumer widget .So that it can change its color according to the app state (that's a favourite toogle button). if i remove the consumer widget everything looks fine as expected . But When in run it with consumer widget wrapped error has been thrown.
This is resulted
This is expected

try to Removed the Expanded widget wrapping the IconButton and directly placed it within the Row to ensure it doesn't overflow.

I think it will work if you just wrap the Padding widget after the Image.network with either Expanded or Flexible.The issue I think is because you have not defined height for Row. But you are telling a child of Row to cover all available space which cause it to overflow.

try this:
  body: GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisExtent: 250, //adjust mainAxisExtent to 250
      ),
    ... //rest of your code


GridView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisExtent: 200,
      ),
      itemCount: products_list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight:Radius.circular(10),topLeft:Radius.circular(10)),
                          child: Image.network(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542234161-b0394bb94542?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D'),
                        ),

                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              products_list[index].name!,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13,),
                              products_list[index].category!,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              '₹ ' + products_list[index].price.toString(),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                              onPressed: () {

                              },
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),

The Unbounded height or the single children is occuping more space is the issue, provided height for the childrens of the Column (First Column of the Card Widget) using Expanded Widget. Expanded widgets shares the  available space equally so i used it for providing height and width
Dont Know why you have created the list inside Widget Builder, instead created it inside the initstate
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
gridItems();

gridItems(){
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  products_list.add(Products(
      name: 'Vaylirk makie vases',
      price: 12.1223,
      productID: 100 + i,
      imageurl: 'sd',
      description: 'sads',
      category: 'Vases'));
}

}

First off all there is no Changenotiferproveider on the parent that is the main reason for this abnormal behaviour

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
